# wget - prevent creating empty directories

Tags: bash, wget

Is there a way to stop wget from creating empty directories?  Most of the files I need are found at one level of depth, i.e. in folder 2 of `/1/2/`, but I need to use infinite recursion because sometimes the file I need is at `1/2/3/` or deeper.  Or at least, I need infinite recursion for the time being, until I figure out the maximum depth of where the files of interest are located.

Right now I'm using

```
wget -nH --cut-dirs=3 -rl 0 -A "*assembly*.txt" ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria
```

Which gets all the files I need, but I am left with a bunch of empty directories.  I would prefer the directory structure `/bacteria/organism/*assembly*.txt`, but if creating multiple subdirectories cannot be avoided, I want to at least stop wget from creating empty directories.  I can, of course, remove the empty directories after running wget, but I want to stop wget from creating them in the first place if possible

Comment: Are the directories on the path to the files you are interested in? Or are they leave directories?

Comment: The empty directories created by wget are not necessarily on the path to the files I am interested.  I do need wget to look in all those subdirectories it is creating, but to only download a file/create a directory if it has a file I am interested in.  So if a directory doesn't have a file I am interested in, it shouldn't create that directory on my system.

Comment: It is also possible to stop wget from creating directories at all with option `--no-directories`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't prevent the directories from being created.

You can do post-processing on the directories though:

```
find bacteria/ -type d -empty -exec rmdir {} \;
```

Looking at a bunch of these directories (including the very busy one for *e. coli*) it appears, as you said, that the only files matching `*assembly*.txt` are stored in the first directory below `bacteria`. Unless there's some variation to this rule, you could just do this:

```
wget -nH --cut-dirs=2 -rl 2 -A "*assembly*.txt" ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria
```

BTW if you want your directory structure to start at `bacteria/` you'll need to change `--cut-dirs` to 2 instead of 3.

Comment: Less than 1/3 of the `*assembly*.txt` files I need are in the first directory unfortunately.  `--cut-dirs=3` worked for me, resulting in `./bacteria/organism/*assembly*.txt`, which makes sense because it cuts 1 - ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov, 2 - genomes, 3 - genbank from  `ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/genbank/bacteria`, leaving just `bacteria/`.  Looks like post processing is the way to go with wget.  I believe I can get the results I want with `lftp` and will report back once tested.

Comment: The `-nH` (no hostname) option already removes the `ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov` folder for you. Or it should.

Comment: your reasoning makes sense, and I had to fiddle with `--cut-dirs` to get what I wanted because it didn't give me what I expected at first.  Strange.